# Why are bootstrap default buttons in bootstrap 3 dark grey for me?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working with Bootstrap 3 RC and the default buttons are dark grey with black text instead of light grey with black text. I have tried both CDN link and offline. I have also emptied my browser cache just in case. Have anyone else experienced this? What could be causing this? Thanks.

edit: I should say that everything else shows just as it should. Even the other kinds of buttons. It's just the `btn btn-default` that is not showing properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the answer from Bootstrap's Github repository:

> The CDN has 3.0.0 RC1; the hosted docs are for git HEAD of the
>   3.0.0-wip branch, where the default button color has changed.

Answer (score 2):

The Bootstrap 3 RC default button is indeed **white background** with a **black text** inside. Please check this [link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons) to make sure you remember what it is supposed to look like.

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to use Bootstrap.

Comment: Why did you down vote? I mean, I am not wrong either. The link has what I said. The current version of Bootstrap has the button like that.

Comment: Saying "check to make sure you remember what it supposed to look like" is not an answer. You could have said that in a comment. In the documentation it looks different from the RC1, so I was confused. Just try it for yourself, then you know what I mean.

Answer (score -2):

If your button is a link_to you can try to simply add `:style`

Example :

```
<%= link_to 'Return', cvs_path, class: "btn btn-primary", :style=>'color:#FFFFFF;' %>
```